# Execution failed for task ':app:installRelease' react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I wanted to create an android apk file in react-native. I followed the instructions as per the link below

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

1. Generated upload key
2. Added gradle variables
3. Added signing config

this worked well but for below command I am getting an error

`npx react-native run-android --variant=release`

**Error:**

> Task :app:installRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installRelease'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.nativebase.market.geekyants.straptaxiapp signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
65 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 63 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installRelease. Run CLI with --verbose flag 
for more details.strong text

Please help..!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem before. Check that you **don't have any other version of the app installed in your phone.** If this is the case, uninstall the previous version and it will work fine.

If that does not work, try updating the version number in the app/build.gradle in the android folder.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running **react-native run-android --variant=release** to build an apk
we usually get such error but that's fine as the error is only because we aren't running an emulator or a real device.

Hence it says that the error is because it is unable to install it as there are no active devices.

I found this error today and everything is fine.

Comment: Indeed, released version of the apk successfully installed on devices, beside `errors/warnings`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but I ran into this as well.  I had to make sure to terminate any running instances of the app on the simulator, device, and terminate Metro. Then this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add:
In my case with respect to @mediaguru's answer - It worked fine on my end just mere uninstalling the installed app in the device (metro was not terminated - because I was in haste to apply the answer, and did not care to read further down to @mediaguru's addition not until mine was solved).

Answer (score 0):

My `gradle.properties` had unsupported parameter, i.e., `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`. Changing this line of code, from:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall Existing App:** Uninstall the existing version of the app from your device or emulator. You can do this using the following command:

```
adb uninstall com.<PackageName>
```